# Change GPS minTime when battery is running low or connected to power, requestLocationUpdates

Tags: gps, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I'm setting the locationManagers settings as following:

```
long MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_GPS_UPDATES = 0; // in min! 
long MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_GPS_UPDATES = 1; //in min!
int DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 0;
mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,(MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_GPS_UPDATES * 60 * 1000), DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, mlocListener);
```

Now, when a charger is connected I would like to decrease the minTime

```
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,(MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_GPS_UPDATES * 60 * 1000), DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, mlocListener);
```

And when I disconnect the charger I want to increase the minTime so the gps gives me an update every minute.

```
mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,(MAX_TIME_BETWEEN_GPS_UPDATES * 60 * 1000), DISTANCE_BETWEEN_UPDATES, mlocListener);
```

So every time I want the change the minTime i call the .removeUpdate function and then the 
.requestLocationUpdates function again to change the setting.

However this doesn't work for me. If i want to change the setting a second time I need to turn of the gps and put it back on again.

Anyone having problems changing the setting (minTime) of the locationManager to change the interval between the location updates?